# How do I display a WebP image in a TImage or just TBitmap?

Tags: delphi, webp

[Delphi-WebP](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-webp/) is a project providing Delphi bindings for [Google's libWebP.dll](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/), which loads WebP images, but the project provides no Delphi-specific image code.
How can I load a WebP image into a TImage or TBitmap?

Comment: Answer from Wrapper author: >>>>Hi,
This api is outdated and have bugs, I should close this project.
I have uptodate api but I stopped my open source activities.

Comment: this is the file format: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#simple_file_format_lossy

Comment: non-native support (via google DLL) https://github.com/Wykerd/delphi-webp

Answer (score 4):

You should develop and register TGraphic sub-class, that can load/save WebP format images, just like TPNGImage, TJPEGImage and TGIFImage classes work.

You can get examples of such classes in recent versions of VCL (JPEG and PNG), on Torry.net or with libraries like:

- http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/
- http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/libs/graphicex-library
- http://galfar.vevb.net/imaging/doc/html/faq.html

Just learn how that was implemented in there projects and do the same for your project of WebP support.

PS. You can also derive your class from `TBitmap` rather than `TGraphic` - that would be less effective but simplier to do. For example of this approach see http://galfar.vevb.net/wp/projects/jpeg2000-for-pascal/
However that would loose all the WebP-specific information and would be "quick and dirty" hack rather than proper VCL-targeted implementation.

Comment: I can't accept. Sorry It's big work, creating TGraphic like class, and I can't load WEBP to TBitmap - which is required or recommended first maybe...

Comment: @Ingo but that means your question is actually rather request "someone, write this for me and give me a link". I doubt you would get any other answers...